# Styled-components astro not load without client:load option

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, astrojs

Hello im trying to use styled-components on my astro-react project, the problem is that when i loaded the component in the index.astro file, i need to specifify the directive client:load, because styled-components render on the client, but i dont want this, because this can make my SEO worse, do you have any solution?

Using styled-components without client:load directive

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.